# OpenCL and Radeon R4 Integrated Graphics

Tags: gpu, opencl, amd-gpu

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with an AMD A6-6310 (Radeon R4 integrated graphics) SoC. I am running Debian Sid (updated to the latest). From wikipedia I see that the R4 Graphics has 128 shader cores across 2 compute units and the main processor being a quad core device.

I believe (correct me if I am wrong), this means that if I run `clinfo` it should detect two platforms, which however detects only one (my Quad core CPU). Can you guys advice me as to how I can get opencl detecting my GPU? I have the `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` and `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` packages installed along with `libdrm-amdgpu1` and `libdrm-radeon1`. From `lspci` I can see that radeon driver is being used. Are there any drivers that need to be installed?

`lspci` output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Kabini/Mullins PSP-Platform Security Processor
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 5
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

`clinfo` output

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
  Platform Vendor                                 The pocl project
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 pocl 1.5, None+Asserts, LLVM 9.0.1, RELOC, SLEEF, DISTRO, POCL_DEBUG
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             POCL

  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     pthread-AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics
  Device Vendor                                   AuthenticAMD
  Device Vendor ID                                0x6c636f70
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 pocl HSTR: pthread-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-btver2
  Driver Version                                  1.5
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 pocl
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               4
  Max clock frequency                             1800MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     4
    Supported partition types                     equally, by counts
    Supported affinity domains                    (n/a)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             4096x4096x4096
  Max work group size                             4096
  Preferred work group size multiple              8
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                               16 / 16      
    int                                                  8 / 8       
    long                                                 4 / 4       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                8 / 8       
    double                                               4 / 4        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              5415717888 (5.044GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           2147483648 (2GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        2097152 (2MiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            134217728 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             8192x8192 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                128
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               1048576 (1024KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max constant buffer size                        1048576 (1024KiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
  printf() buffer size                            16777216 (16MiB)
  Built-in kernels                                (n/a)
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Portable Computing Language
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [POCL]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [POCL]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Portable Computing Language
    Device Name                                   pthread-AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Portable Computing Language
    Device Name                                   pthread-AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Portable Computing Language
    Device Name                                   pthread-AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.12
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 2.2
```

Please do let me know if I should provide any further information.

Looking forward to working with opencl soon. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Radeon and AMDGPU](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo) refer to [two](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI) [generations](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU) of AMD drivers. Radeon works on older GPUs and AMDGPU on newer ones. Neither implements OpenCL for CPUs (x86-64). Therefore you do not have an OpenCL implementation for your CPU.

That being said, AMD started dropping the OpenCL implementation for their CPUs for a [while](https://community.amd.com/thread/231410), though [ROCm still seems to support it](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/aun3y2/amd_cpus_no_longer_have_opencl_support/eha5j2t/), somehow, as the [documentation](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/) mentions CPUs only in one image, everything else being about GPUs. That is also true of the [supported hadware list on their Github](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm#Hardware-and-Software-Support).

However, there is still [pocl](http://portablecl.org/), which uses LLVM to target various devices, including x86-64.